# Using ServiceStack v4 with Elmah

Tags: servicestack, elmah

Is there any up-to-date guide that will help with integration of Elmah into ServiceStack for logging? Anything I look, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080911/using-elmah-with-servicestack-mvc) is out of date since methods changed.

Ideally I would like to [receive error emails like described on this link](http://rossipedia.com/blog/2013/03/elmah-emails-and-servicestack/), but for start I would just love to be able to go to elmah.axd and see all unhandled errors.

I've already installed Elmah and configured web.config (which I've done using NuGet). Now I'm stuck as to what to do after doing Install-Package ServiceStack.Logging.Elmah - most of old tutorials say that I need to use NLog (which I don't want to do - since I don't want multiple logging components).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This post should cover it: http://blog.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-servicestack/

The post explains how to integrate with the elmah.io logger, but the method is the same for other types of ErrorLog implementations for ELMAH. Instead of installing the elmah.io NuGet package, you can install the ELMAH package, which gives you a default set of configuration in your web.config using the memory error log.